# I want to develop a socket based chatting app in Titanium compatible with Android, iPhone and Blackberry

Tags: titanium

I want to develop a socket based chatting app in Titanium compatible with Android, iPhone and Blackberry.

Please give me suggestion about it

Comment: Try with socket.io and nodejs, they should be Titanium compatible.

Comment: can we use external javascript library in titanium ?

Comment: [This is supported already in Titanium.](http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/api/v1/chats/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a "socket based chatting app", then you've already made decisions about the implementation, and so you really just need to know the interface for implementing it. Try reading the fantastic manual, it is very detailed on how to use sockets.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Network.Socket.TCP

You'll need to roll your own server side to accept the socket connections, and your own protocol for the communications. Or adhere to an existing protocol.

Or you can use the existing, working Ti.Cloud sample I created. It is the Titanium specific version of what Hini linked at nodeacs.cloud.appcelerator.com --

https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.cloud/tree/master/commonjs/example/windows/chats

Comment: I am using Titanium.Network.Socket.TCP and I am able to chat but now I want to create lister like friends request, accept, new message, friend is online etc. Is it possible to do using Titanium.Network.Socket.TCP

Comment: Sockets are just a communication mechanism, they can do anything. You're reinventing the wheel, you should use at least some of the work already done in the Ti.Cloud module for friends, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Titanium along with Node ACS to create the application.
Here is a sample chat application tutorial. I hope it helps you.

http://nodeacs.cloud.appcelerator.com/guides/quickstart